# I am getting an error message from a Tkinter module I am trying to use

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to use a Tkinter module as suggested on the following website: https://likegeeks.com/python-gui-examples-tkinter-tutorial/. My expectation was to create my first GUI application as shown on the website by creating window = Tk(). Instead, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Daniel/Desktop/Python Projects/untitled-2.py", line 3, in <module>
    pass
  File "C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2018, in __init__
    baseName = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
builtins.IndexError: list index out of range
```

I do not know what is causing this error but it appears chronic. My code is the same as the following:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
```

Please advise me of what I need to do in order to address this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: It seems like you have executed something like `sys.argv.pop()`, otherwise `sys.argv[0]` should be the script name.  The posted code should not produce such error.

Comment: Try executing `sys.argv[0]=__file__` before the call to `Tk`

Comment: Thanks. I took a cue from your comment and implemented sys.argv.append(__file__). The file is now working as expected. I have had this issue for over a year now and I am so glad that it is finally over!

Comment: This is actually not a solution.  There may be something corrupted in your Python installation that need to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you should try the following!

---

**1st Method: Try reinstalling `OS` and `Tkinter` module**

1. Open `CMD`
2. Type these commands one after the other:

```
py -m pip uninstall os
py -m pip uninstall tkinter
```

3. Reinstall these modules using the following commands:

```
py -m pip install os
py -m pip install tkinter
```

Now try running your program again.

---

**2nd Method: Reinstall Python**

1. Open `Contrl Pannel<Program and Features` then find the Python Application in the list. Then uninstall it.
2. Download the setup of Python from: https://www.python.org/downloads/
3. Find the version you want and then download the setup. Reinstall Python just as you did before.

Now try again with the program. It is most likely to work.

---

Thank You! :)

Comment: `os` and `tkinter` are standard libraries in Python installation, they cannot be installed using `pip`.

Comment: Oh No! I seriously forgot it.